# is $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ open in $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ under the sup metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ open in $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ under the sup metric? $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is the set of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ is the set of all bounded function. We are working with the sup metric here. I usually like to have a visual or geometric image when working with problems, but I am having difficulty picturing what an open set even is in a function space or sequence space. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we call a set open, if every element in it has "wiggle room."

Now the set $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is actually easier to visualize than some of the more abstract metric spaces. An epsilon ball around a continuous function is just an epsilon range over that function in the coordinate plane, so I think $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is open in $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$. Is that true?

Comment: Hint: Recall that the only open subspaces of a normed linear space are the whole space and the empty set!

Comment: Hint: Given a bounded continuous function, can we have a discontinuous bounded function with the same bounds? Now, what can we think about the "wiggle spaces" about the zero function (which is continuous)?

Answer (score 1):

The comment of @Brozovic is very Smart. But let's ignore that $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is a subspace of $\mathcal B[0,1]$, and let see how to prove that $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is not an open subset of $B[0,1]$.

---

*Hint*

For all $\varepsilon >0$, $$\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}\in \mathcal B(0,\varepsilon )=\{g\in \mathcal B[0,1]\mid \|g\|<\varepsilon \}.$$